# I do not get a title

Tags: titles

I am using a template from the link:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamerposter

It does not show a title, the `example.tex` has a `\title`, but it does not appear on the poster.

Please tell me how to correct this problem.

Comment: Also note that you may have a problem with some titles showing up when you compile to a .dvi file, which are fixed when you make it into a .pdf

Answer (score 4):

We will be only supplying the metadata when we type `\title{...}` etc. But to display them one should issue a `\maketitle` command. Putting `\maketitle` immediately after the `\begin{frame}` displays a title.

Obligatory code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>
  {
% you can chose your theme here:
\usetheme{Berlin}
% further beamerposter themes are available at
% http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php
}
  \usepackage{type1cm}
  \usepackage{calc}
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
  \graphicspath{{figures/}}
  \title[Fancy Posters]{Making Really Fancy Posters with \LaTeX}
  \author[Dreuw \& Deselaers]{Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers}
  \institute[RWTH Aachen University]{Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition,RWTH Aachen University}
  \newcommand{\footlinetext}{Lehrstuhl f\"ur Informatik 6 - Computer Science Department - RWTH Aachen University - Aachen, Germany \par Mail: \texttt{<surname>@cs.rwth-aachen.de} \hfill WWW: \texttt{http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de}\vskip1ex}
  \date{Jul. 31th, 2007}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
  \maketitle %%% <--- put it here.
    \vfill
    \begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
      \centering
      {\tiny tiny}\par
      {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
      {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
      {\normalsize normalsize}\par
      {\large large}\par
      {\Large Large}\par
      {\LARGE LARGE}\par
      {\veryHuge VeryHuge}\par
      {\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
      {\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
    \end{block}
    \vfill
    \vfill
    \begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
      \centering
      {\tiny tiny}\par
      {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
      {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
      {\normalsize normalsize}\par
      {\large large}\par
      {\Large Large}\par
      {\LARGE LARGE}\par
      {\veryHuge VeryHuge}\par
      {\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
      {\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
    \end{block}
    \vfill
    \begin{columns}[t]
      \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{Introduction}

          \begin{itemize}
          \item[]
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item some items
            \item some items
            \item some items
            \item some items
            \end{enumerate}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{Introduction}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item some items and $\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \end{itemize}
          $$\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$$
        \end{block}

        \begin{block}{Introduction}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \end{itemize}
        \end{block}

        \begin{block}{Introduction}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item some items and $\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \item some items
          \end{itemize}
          $$\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$$
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]